# where rescue should be called in an EWF_APP to be able to close a database connection

Tags: exception, eiffel, eiffel-web-framework

Inheriting from `WSF_FILTERED_ROUTER_EXECUTION` I redefine the `clean` to be able to close DB Connections. But when there is an assertion failure, I don't know where to call the `clean` on a rescue clause. In which feature do I have to call my clean on a `rescue` clause??

Answer (score 1):

Check `WSF_EXECUTION.clean` which is called after each request execution.
There is also `WSF_EXECUTION.execute_rescue (e: detachable EXCEPTION)` .

You can redefine any of them for your purpose.

But I recommend rescuing as early as possible, this way you may be able to have a proper handling, rather than a default one.

Comment: the clean doesnt seem to be called on case of exception, thx for the other!!!